# Proof that entropic quasigroup reduce to abelian group.

Tags: group-theory

In "[Entropoids: Groups in Disguise](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/583.pdf)",

The author made the following claim:

> **Theorem 1.** For every entropic quasigroup $(G,*)$, there exists an abelian group $(G, \cdot)$, commuting automorphisms $\sigma \tau$ of $(G, \cdot)$ and an element $c \in G$ such that:
>
> $$ x*y = x^\sigma \cdot y^\tau \cdot c $$

where entropic quasigroup is being defined as:

> $$ (a*b)*(c*d) = (a*c)*(b*d) $$

The author mentions that this had been proven in [1], [2], and [3],

I took time to read the 3 papers, and found that, they're making additional arithmetic assumptions.

For example,

- in [1], there's

> Lemma 12. If an abelian quasigroup $Q$ possesses a (unique, two-sided) unit element $u$, it is an abelian group.

- in [3], Theorem 1. assumed an $+$ operation in addition to $\cdot$.

**Q**: What I'd like to know, can or has Theorem 1 be/been proven for arbitrary closure with the entropic property?

[1] Richard H. Bruck, [Some Results in the Theory of Quasigroups](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1944-055-00/S0002-9947-1944-0009963-X/S0002-9947-1944-0009963-X.pdf), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **55** (1) (1944), 19–52.

[2] David C. Murdoch, [Quasi-Groups Which Satisfy Certain Generalized Associative Laws](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371517), *American Journal of Mathematics* **61** (2) (1939), 509–522.

[3] Kôshichi Toyoda, [On axioms of linear functions](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/pjab1912/17/7/17_7_221/_pdf/-char/en),  *Proc. Imp. Acad. Tokyo* **17** (7) (1941), 221–227.

Comment: You said you found they're making additional arithmetic assumptions - expand?

Comment: @Candlebeam I've added what I've thought of as additional assumption in [1] and [3].

Comment: In [1] the proof for lemma 12 is right under it: "If we let a =d = u in (72) we derive bc = cb, so that Q is commutative. Again from (72), with c = u, we find ab-d=a-bd, so that Q is associative.
Hence Q is an abelian group." In [3] the author is defining, not assuming, a "+" operation.

Comment: In fact, the correctness of the proofs in the cited sources is the reason the result is usually called the Toyoda-Bruck Theorem or Toyoda-Bruck-Murdoch Theorem, up to permutation of the names.